# Python Pandas: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe from which I picked unique values, and it resulted in an ndarray  ("unManager") of shape (1187,)... just one column.

Now, I have written a function to group some rows of the dataframe, do calculations and add values in the ndarray.

I am using apply on the ndarray ("unManager") for that, and am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-ff7e78ab33a7> in <module>()
----> 1 unManager.apply(runThis, axis=0)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Now, when I am trying to convert the ndarray ("unManager") to a dataframe, through:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(unManager,index=unManager[0])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3ee3d2605321> in <module>()
----> 1 dfs = pd.DataFrame(unManager,index=unManager[0])
.
.
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'actama99,CLE' was passed
```

'actama99,CLE' here is first value of the ndarray  ("unManager") of shape (1187,).

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: You should use applymap in this case. Also, for the second problem, you can try the following `dfs = pd.DataFrame(unManager).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(unManager,index=unManager[0])
```

`unManager[0]` returns a scalar and that is not a `collection`.

you want

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame(dict(unManagers=unManager))
```

Comment: Thanks. Now when I run the apply function...
dfs.apply(func, axis=0)

I get the error:
ValueError: ('Series lengths must match to compare', 'occurred at index unManagers')